# Отработает ли javascript в данном случае?

Tags: php

**index.html**

```
<form action="api.php">
  <button type="submit">submit</button>
</form>
```

нажимаю `submit`

**api.php**

```
<?php
  header("Location: $_SERVER['HTTP_REFERER']");
?>

<script>
var a = 1
</script>
```

успеет ли выполнится js перед отправкой на  **index.html**
или нужно писать exit()

Comment: Помоему должен исполниться. Попробуйте вместо js написать php код который будет записывать произвольную строку в файл. Если строка в файле появится,  значит и js отработает.

Comment: Хотя нее, я ерунду написал). Пхп то исполниться , js не исполниться